# PRAW: Reddit API returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: praw

I've read a lot of the threads on this site about solving Reddit 403 errors, none have solved my problem.

I just created a reddit account and made a simple bot. I authenticated and checked that the credentials were valid (they are), then tried to make a post to r/test.

```
subreddit = reddit.subreddit("test")
subreddit.submit("Blah blah this is a test",selftext="Some random text here to test it out and whatnot")
```

I ran the code and got this error:

```
prawcore.exceptions.ResponseException: received 403 HTTP response
```

How do I fix this? Is my account banned from the API? Do I need to "age" the account for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem. You will need to change your user agent to something a bit more verbose. I had my user agent as `Bot (by u/username)`, but after changing "bot" to something a bit more complex everything worked!